# get a state name after comma

Tags: python, regex

I hope to get a state name in the sentence same as "12345 Big Street, New York 12345 United States". I hope to catch "New York", but I do not know how to get the state name between a comma and the zip code by regular expression in python.

Have tried some regular expression, it can get the word after the comma, but it only catch "New" rather than "New York"

Comment: To get help on StackOverflow, it's generally best to share the code you've tried, show what that produced and what you were expecting. Otherwise, it looks like you asking others to do your programming for you.

Comment: **Have tried some regular expression**, post those you tried.

Comment: you could at least use `text.split(",")[1]` to remove parts before state name. And later you have to catch number to find end of state name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe, this simple expression might be working just OK:

```
(?i)\b(?:New\s+York|New\s+Jersey|Vermont|and other states goes here)\b
```

and you can similarly do for the 2 letters, if you had those:

```
(?i)\b(?:ca|ma|mo|va|ny|nj|and others)\b
```

#### Test

```
import re

string = """
2345 Big Street, New York 12345 United States
2345 Big Street, new jersey, 12345-1234 United States
2345 Big Street, NJ, 12345-4321 US
2345 Big Street, MA  12345 U.S.
"""

expression = r'(?i)\b(?:New\s+York|New\s+Jersey|Vermont|and other states goes here)\b'
matches = re.findall(expression, string)

print(matches)
```

#### Output

```
['New York', 'new jersey']
```

---

> If you wish to explore/simplify/modify the expression, it's been
>   explained on the top right panel of
>   [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/JjRHO1/1/). If you'd like, you
>   can also watch in [this
>   link](https://regex101.com/r/JjRHO1/1/debugger), how it would match
>   against some sample inputs.

---

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Another way would be (simpler I think):

```
>>> addr = '12345 Big Street, New York 12345 United States'
>>> state, = re.search(r', ([a-zA-Z\s]+)', addr).groups(0)
>>> state.rstrip() # remove trailing spaces
'New York'
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `(?<=,\s).*(?=\s\d)`, which makes use of a positive look-behind on a comma followed by a space, along with a positive look-ahead on a space followed by a digit.

`"12345 Big Street, New York 12345 United States"` --> `New York`

This can be seen working on Regex101 [here](https://regex101.com/r/gbmu84/1).

Answer (score 0):

A rather simple solution that works if all your input strings are of the same type as you sample.

```
txt = "12345 Big Street, New York 12345 United States"
comma_idx = re.search(",", txt).start()
txt_after_comma = txt[comma_idx+1:]

number_idx =  re.search("\d", txt_after_comma).start()
txt_before_number = txt_after_comma[:number_idx]
print(txt_before_number.strip())
```

output:

```
New York
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex which should capture the city name having space(s) or without any space in first grouping pattern.

```
,\s+(\D+)(?=\s+\d)
```

**Explanation:**

- `,\s+` - Matches a comma and then one or more whitespace
- `(\D+)` - Captures any thing not having numbers as city names most likely doesn't contain numbers
- `(?=\s+\d)` - This look ahead ensures the match stops just before one or more whitespace followed by a number which should be the zip

[regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/j4Y7mC/1)

Python code,

```
import re

s = "12345 Big Street, New York 12345 United States"
m = re.search(r',\s+(\D+)(?=\s+\d)', s)
if m:
 print(m.group(1)) # print contents of group1
```

Output:

```
New York
```